# How do i release previous version of package using semantic-release

Tags: npm, semantic-release

I have a npm package which i publish with [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) . My master branch is currently on version 2.0.1 , but we recently found a bug for version v1.0.5 and need to fix it by releasing v1.0.6, I checked out from v1.0.5 branch and fixed the bug, but when i push changes, it automatically creates version from master branch i.e creates v2.0.2, how do we force semantic-release to release package for previous version ?

Comment: Did you find what to do?

Comment: no, not using semantic-release, had to release manually by creating a release in github